# How to Cap off Broken Hot Water Radiators in Heating System and then Pressure Test System

Tags: plumbing, boiler, radiator, water-circulating-heating

I'm working on a house and I want to remove a few broken hot water radiators  (Freeze Damage) so I can test the rest of the system for leaks and integrity.

**Capping Off Broken Radiators, or run a temporary line between them?**
Any tips on capping off the broken radiators to temporarily eliminate them from the system so I can test the rest of it? Can I just cap both ends (Water Inlet/Outlet), or must I put a cap on the inlet, and some sort of valve on the outlet end? I've see some people put vents on the outlet end but unsure if those are required if I'm just capping temporarily for testing before I replace the radiators. I've also read that some suggest putting a temporary line of pex between the inlet and outlet so the system can flow as it normally does from inlet to outlet.  What is recommended here?

**Filling system with air pressure for testing for leaks**
Any tips on testing system with air pressure before getting the system filled with water for testing?
What is standard process to test the system if it holds air pressure? I've seen some say to just fill with water and look for leaks but if testing with pressure is ideal, I'll do that first. What is best method here and what PSI (I've read 12-25 psi for a two story house), and where is best place to fill system?

Any tips on getting the broken radiators capped off or temporary path patched in, and then pressure testing the system will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Imagine the broken rads are just from looking at pieces fallen off.  Would be concern about the others that do not look broken, might be weaken or just hanging together by a hair.  Imagine also all the pipes are metal(copper/steel) and they also need careful checking.  Might be cheaper to toss everything and look into a heat pump system.

Comment: Thanks @crip659, I'm assuming most radiators are broken so I will be pressure testing anything individually that isn't broken. You make a good point though and is something to consider.  I have access to a lot of the piping so I will be visually inspecting a lot of it as well, but the hope is to get some air in the system to see what defects I find.

Comment: Imagine the boiler(the tank) might even have freeze damage.  Guess it goes below 32F/0C for a long time where you are, it does here.

Comment: @crip659, Another great point.  Oddly certain things broke, and others did not. The basement didn't seem to have any damage even to more simple water piping so it seems the damage was mostly on the upper floors. So the boiler may be safe.

Comment: did you pressure test the whole system with air ? just to spare time on individual testing.

Comment: @Ruskes, I did not yet, I have visible cracks/broken radiators so I need to eliminate them from the system so I can test the rest of it. I'm hoping for some general tips on how to test the entire system with air, not just individual radiators yet. My hope is to remove known broken radiators and cap or put a temporary loop in place, and then test system to see what else is broken if anything.

Comment: I assume the heater and the pump are in the basement. Open the inlet and return and install T junctions with valves. You will need that in the future to drain the system to prevent freezing. Maybe you have that set up already. Install a pressure gauge on inlet and outlet. Remove the damaged and bypass. with high pressure hose. Pressurize and let it stand overnight, and note the pressure. You might have air release valves in the system. Close those temporarily.

Comment: Thanks @Ruskes, yes they are in the basement and it has lots of valves already in place. Any suggestions on how much pressure? Is 12-15PS of air ideal for a residential small house with 2 floors?

Comment: Start with 10 PSI and observe for leaks